# How display the href link in the footnote?

Tags: footnotes, links

My document has several `\href` that I would like to be shown on the footnote. How can I do it?

Comment: See also [Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12855/2975).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I usually write something like this, so the entry is hyperlinked for onscreen reading but there's also a footnote to the URL for paper output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\fnurl[2]{%
  \href{#2}{#1}\footnote{\url{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
hello \fnurl{Google}{www.google.com}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful! ... for people like me who want to replace the `\href` with the suggested `\fnurl`: The syntax of `href` is inversed, i.e. `\href{#1}{#2}\footnote{\url{#1}}` can be used with the typical `\href{www.google.com}{Google}` syntax

Comment: That href replacement didn't quite work, but this one from the duplicate question did:

`\let\oldhref\href\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{#2}\footnote{\url{#1}}}`