# Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, verbatim

This is basically an expanded version of part of [Control command arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/control-command-arguments) .  The original questioner there wants to redefine `\href` so that all the links end up in foonotes (rather than in the main document) so my suggestion was the old `\let\oldcmd=\cmd \def\cmd{reimplement \cmd in some fancy way}` trick.  Turned out that that didn't solve the problem.  But what broke this solution isn't really about the solution, it's about those @&*@%y$#@ characters in URLs and ... *sigh* ... footnotes.

Not being an expert on `hyperref`, I appeal to the community to help.  (And half an hour gazing at the documentation and source of `hyperref` has not brought enlightenment either.)  I've tried the solutions at [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote) and [Is there a reliable footnote command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/is-there-a-reliable-footnote-command) to no avail (though perhaps I'm doing them wrong ... sorry, incorrectly).  Also, note that [How display the href link in the footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/how-display-the-href-link-in-the-footnote) is the wrong way around for this: the questioner wants the clickable link in the footnote.

Here's the URL that the questioner presented me with, embedded in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{\href{http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{b}} world.

\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   s
l.9 ...qi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{b}}
                                                   world.
```

which makes me think that it is the `#` that is causing the problem.

Comment: The most straightforward solution is just to use `\#` instead of `#`. I’m not sure the benefits from your solution justify going the extra mile here: even in HTML (which was, after all, developed in close connection with the URL syntax), when you want to use such URLs you have to *manually* escape parts of them.

Comment: you could just use an URL shortener like http://is.gd to get an URL without special characters...

Comment: @Konrad: but we built computers to do things *for* us!

Comment: @Andrew: Note my updated answer (now even easier!) ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `url` package (used by `hyperref`) gives you the `\Url@HyperHook` hook, which is also used in `\urldef` (see [Getting percent sign into an URL in a footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote/12233#12233)).
The original URL string is located in `\Url@String` (expandable) and the already formatted string in `\Url@FormatString` (not expandable).

This can be used to implement your own `\url` like macros. The code below then creates the wanted `\footnote` with an `\href`. A second macro is required to read the second argument of `\href` after the URL. This is a little tricky because the rest of the internal code of `\url` most be jumped over first and then reinserted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\def\hreffootnote{%
    %\unskip % maybe required
    \begingroup
    \def\Url@HyperHook ##1\endgroup{%
        \let\Url@HyperHook\relax
        \href@footnote
    }%
    \url
}

\let\realhref\href
\def\href@footnote#1\endgroup#2{%
   \footnote{\expandafter\realhref\expandafter{\Url@String}{#2}}%
   \endgroup\endgroup#1\endgroup%  #1 is some internal `\url` code
}


\begin{document}

Text\hreffootnote{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

Text \href{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

\let\href\hreffootnote
Text \href{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

Hello\hreffootnote{http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{b} world.


\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively a home made solution which reads the first argument verbatim (except `{ }` characters):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\def\hreffootnote{%
    %\unskip
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\{=1\relax
    \catcode`\}=2\relax
    \href@footnote
}
\def\href@footnote#1{%
    \endgroup
    \href@@footnote{#1}%
}
\let\realhref\href
\def\href@@footnote#1#2{%
    \footnote{\realhref{#1}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

Text\hreffootnote{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

Text \href{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

\let\href\hreffootnote
Text \href{http://foobar.com/~test/%^&*$_##/test}{there} after

Hello\hreffootnote{http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{b} world.

\end{document}
```

---

### Update 2011-07-27:

I now published a new version of [`newverbs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newverbs) which provides `\collectverb` and `\Collectverb` to collect verbatim arguments easily. For the sake of completeness here again the full solution based on this package. (It is also an answer to [Changing href's to footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12774/changing-hrefs-to-footnotes/24182#24182)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newverbs}[2011/07/24]

\let\orighref\href
\renewcommand{\href}{\Collectverb{\hrefii}}
\newcommand\hrefii[2]{\footnote{\orighref{#1}{#2}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Dummy text
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\href{http://test.com/%$^£$%^_@~}{Test URL}

% With other argument separators as { }:
\lipsum*[2]\href|http://test.com/%$^£$}{%^_@~|{Test URL}

% If a real \href is wanted (also used for comparison here)
\lipsum*[3]\orighref{http://test.com/%$^£$%^_@~}{Test URL}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that you should add this as a solution to the original question as well.

Comment: @Andrew: [done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/control-command-arguments/12890#12890) + added explanation how to define macros which read an argument verbatim.

Comment: After a couple of hours fighting beamer I found this, very useful with beamer!

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`bigfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello\footnote{\href{http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{b}} world.

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work to solve the original questioner's problem, since putting this into another macro definition seems to break it.

Comment: Nonetheless, it answers the question that I actually asked and is a simpler method if one _doesn't_ want to wrap it in a new macro.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This definition seems to work with the hyperref package. `\hyper@normalise` takes care of all those nasty characters.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myhref@[2]{#2\footnote{\url@{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myhref}{\hyper@normalise\myhref@}
\makeatother
```

Edit: This typesets the link as a footnote. To just get a footnote with a link labelled by the text in the second argument, this should work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hreffootnote@[2]{\footnote{\hyper@linkurl{\Hurl{#2}}{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hreffootnote}{\hyper@normalise\hreffootnote@}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Useful to know, but it doesn't quite emulate what `\footnote{\href{a}{b}}` should do as `\href{a}{b}` creates a link to `a` with the text `b` so the URL isn't visible in the document.

Comment: Nice answer. I forgot that `hyperref` gives you `\hyper@normalise` which does basically the same as the code in my answer, but does it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: *do not use this answer: the "bigfoot" answer above is (probably) **much** better.*

My idea is to make `#` active document-wide, and let it to a macro parameter character, so that it can still be used in definitions (e.g. in the definition of `\href`). In the troublesome parts, we can disable the `#`: simply `\let` it to be equal to `\relax`, in other words, to do nothing.

The only reason why we cannot make `#` active before loading `hyperref` is that this package itself makes `#` active, and for some reason that I did not track down, `hyperref` is not happy with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let \macro@parameter@character #
\catcode`\#=13
\let #\macro@parameter@character
\let\href@old\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\footnote{\let##\relax\href@old{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\href{http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}{c} world.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked fine for me:

```
Hello\footnote{\url{http://www.google.com/\#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=numbers&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=d5033c56880e0199}}{b} world.
```

The scheme is as follows: `\footnote{\url{yoururl\#yoururl}}`

Comment: The question is explicitly about `\href` and *not* `\url`.