# How to use a link as footnote that has special characters inside?

Tags: footnotes

I want to use the following footnote:

```
\footnote{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826%28Surface.10%29.aspx}
```

But the problem is since there are % symbols in the link, it is recognized as a comment. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't it enough to simple escape the % with \ or am I missing something here?
That is:

```
\footnote{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826\%28Surface.10\%29.aspx}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just escape it as per jonalv's post or use the `\url` command from either the `url` package of better `hyperref` as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\footnote{{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826\%28Surface.10\%29.aspx}}

\footnote{\url{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826\%28Surface.10\%29.aspx}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you still need to escape % when using `\url` in another macro. The automatic handling of active characters by `\url` and `\href` only works on the top-level.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to escape %, another solution was discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote/).

In short, load hyperref and define a new macro `\urlfootnote` as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\urlfootnote@[1]{\footnote{\url@{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\urlfootnote}{\hyper@normalise\urlfootnote@}
\makeatother
```

Now, you can type

```
\urlfootnote{http:///msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826%28Surface.10%29.aspx}
```

This will also typeset the URL in typewriter font and make it a link. If you don't want this, replace the definition of `\urlfootnote@` by `\newcommand\urlfootnote@[1]{\footnote{#1}}`.

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to use

```
\urldef{\urlB}\url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch}
```

as described in this question [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495823/url-not-working-in-footnotes-seems-to-require-escape-characters-but).