# Insert a url in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, fancyhdr, urls

I would like to insert a url in a footnote but that isn't working.

I use the following code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[french]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\FrenchLabelItem}{\textbullet}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{\arrayrulewidth}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.65cm, bottom=2.65cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and the problem is in this "sentence" :

```
\,\footnote{La vidéo réalisée à l'effet du projet Arqana Racing Club est visible sur le lien suivant : \url{http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5o0t29uwTQc#!}}
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: You should load the `hyperref` package the last. And, could you please get rid of unnecessary packages so that, you get to a MWE: note that a MWE is a complete example beginning with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I have already this package in my code

Comment: But, you have loaded this package before a couple of other packages. Make that the last loaded one, by moving it to the end. Further, `hyperref` package loads `url`, so I don't think you don't have to load it.

Comment: Escape `&` and `#` in the argument of `\url`. In other words, substitute `\&` for `&` and `\#` for `#`; that should solve the problem.

Comment: oh yes, my mistake I forgot that.

Comment: Tangentially related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13224/10679

Comment: Related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote

Comment: @jub0bs Escaping `&` and `#`  works here too but what should I do with   `\footnote{\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WFF_%27N_PROOF}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

The @Jubobs' comment is right.

I forgot substitute & and # by \& and #.

That is working like that. Thanks.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: You do not have to escape the `&` character.