# How can I open an online .pdf to a specific page from a LaTeX generate .pdf from footnote?

Tags: cross-referencing, pdf, urls

I'm try to open a .pdf to a specific page from my pdf generate using pdflatex, this is a valid `url`that do what I want in my browser:

http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf#page=4

`#page=4` indicate the page I want to open, but it seems that when I use it in a `\footnote`doesn't work:

```
\footnote{\url{http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf#page=4}}
```

In my LaTeX document, doesn't work I've got this error:

`Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.<to be read again>p ....icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf#page=4}}`

Caused by `#page=4`. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
words words words \footnote{\url{http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf#page=4}}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE? If you use the [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) package with your `\url{http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf#page=4}`, there is no error...

Comment: Are you using `\url{<something with #>}` in an argument to another macro?

Comment: Well, as a quick fix you can enable it by using `\ `.  Like this:  `\footnote{\url{http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf\#page=4}}`

Comment: You should take a look at these couple of questions (possible duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13224/how-to-use-a-link-as-footnote-that-has-special-characters-inside http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12230/getting-percent-sign-into-an-url-in-a-footnote and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote

Comment: @Mario Yes I think i should delate the question...

Comment: Don't worry, it will be marked as duplicate.  It's better, since this will allow people who ask questions like you follow the same answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible solutions

1. Using `\` to scape the special character, i.e., `\footnote{\url{http://www.icomos.org/charters/venice_e.pdf\#page=4}}`
2. Use a new command named `\urlfootnote`, as described by the following code in your preamble:

**Code**

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\urlfootnote@[1]{\footnote{\url@{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\urlfootnote}{\hyper@normalise\urlfootnote@}
\makeatother
```

3. Define it at the beginning of your code, like this:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\urldef\myurl\url{foo%.com}
\begin{document}
text\footnote{WWW: \myurl}
\end{document}
```

4. Martin's complete answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12864/27833