# \@footnotetext error for special characters

Tags: footnotes, urls, markdown

I have a link [3NT](http://www.xinruibridge.com/deallog/DealLog.html?bidlog=1C,P,1S,P%3B1N,P,3N,P%3BP,P&playlog=W:3D,JD,5D,7D%3BN:2S,4S,6S,KS%3BW:AD,6D,TD,9D%3BW:5S,3S,TS,7S%3BE:6H,5H,8H,QH%3BN:KH,2H,TH,3H%3BN:QD,JH,KD,8D%3BS:AH,4D,9S,9H%3BS:AC,2C,4C,8C%3BS:JC,7C,9C,7H%3BS:3C,5C,TC,4H%3BN:KC,JS,6C,QC%3BN:QS,AS,8S,2D%3B&deal=876.AT5.K97.AJ63%20K5.83.A8432.Q752%20Q932.KQ.QJ6.KT94%20AJT4.J97642.T5.8&vul=All&dealer=S&contract=3N&declarer=S&wintrick=9&score=600&str=%E5%9B%A2%E4%BD%93%E8%B5%9B%20%E7%AC%AC7%E8%BD%AE%20%E7%89%8C%E5%8F%B7%207/12&dealid=349432067&pbnid=65731689&from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0) to external website

I defined it in markdown like below

```
link [3NT](http://www.xinruibridge.com/deallog/DealLog.html?bidlog=1C,P,1S,P%3B1N,P,3N,P%3BP,P&playlog=W:3D,JD,5D,7D%3BN:2S,4S,6S,KS%3BW:AD,6D,TD,9D%3BW:5S,3S,TS,7S%3BE:6H,5H,8H,QH%3BN:KH,2H,TH,3H%3BN:QD,JH,KD,8D%3BS:AH,4D,9S,9H%3BS:AC,2C,4C,8C%3BS:JC,7C,9C,7H%3BS:3C,5C,TC,4H%3BN:KC,JS,6C,QC%3BN:QS,AS,8S,2D%3B&deal=876.AT5.K97.AJ63%20K5.83.A8432.Q752%20Q932.KQ.QJ6.KT94%20AJT4.J97642.T5.8&vul=All&dealer=S&contract=3N&declarer=S&wintrick=9&score=600&str=%E5%9B%A2%E4%BD%93%E8%B5%9B%20%E7%AC%AC7%E8%BD%AE%20%E7%89%8C%E5%8F%B7%207/12&dealid=349432067&pbnid=65731689&from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0)
```

Which in my application, it will generate related LaTex with footnote below, it complains `File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\href{http://www.xinruibridge.com/deallog/DealLog.html?bidlog=1C,P,1S,P%3B1N,P,3N,P%3BP,P&playlog=W:3D,JD,5D,7D%3BN:2S,4S,6S,KS%3BW:AD,6D,TD,9D%3BW:5S,3S,TS,7S%3BE:6H,5H,8H,QH%3BN:KH,2H,TH,3H%3BN:QD,JH,KD,8D%3BS:AH,4D,9S,9H%3BS:AC,2C,4C,8C%3BS:JC,7C,9C,7H%3BS:3C,5C,TC,4H%3BN:KC,JS,6C,QC%3BN:QS,AS,8S,2D%3B&deal=876.AT5.K97.AJ63%20K5.83.A8432.Q752%20Q932.KQ.QJ6.KT94%20AJT4.J97642.T5.8&vul=All&dealer=S&contract=3N&declarer=S&wintrick=9&score=600&str=%E5%9B%A2%E4%BD%93%E8%B5%9B%20%E7%AC%AC7%E8%BD%AE%20%E7%89%8C%E5%8F%B7%207/12&dealid=349432067&pbnid=65731689&from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0}{3NT}\footnote{\href{http://www.xinruibridge.com/deallog/DealLog.html?bidlog=1C,P,1S,P%3B1N,P,3N,P%3BP,P&playlog=W:3D,JD,5D,7D%3BN:2S,4S,6S,KS%3BW:AD,6D,TD,9D%3BW:5S,3S,TS,7S%3BE:6H,5H,8H,QH%3BN:KH,2H,TH,3H%3BN:QD,JH,KD,8D%3BS:AH,4D,9S,9H%3BS:AC,2C,4C,8C%3BS:JC,7C,9C,7H%3BS:3C,5C,TC,4H%3BN:KC,JS,6C,QC%3BN:QS,AS,8S,2D%3B&deal=876.AT5.K97.AJ63%20K5.83.A8432.Q752%20Q932.KQ.QJ6.KT94%20AJT4.J97642.T5.8&vul=All&dealer=S&contract=3N&declarer=S&wintrick=9&score=600&str=%E5%9B%A2%E4%BD%93%E8%B5%9B%20%E7%AC%AC7%E8%BD%AE%20%E7%89%8C%E5%8F%B7%207/12&dealid=349432067&pbnid=65731689&from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0}{http:\slash \slash www.xinruibridge.com\slash deallog\slash DealLog.html?bidlog=1C,P,1S,P\%3B1N,P,3N,P\%3BP,P\&playlog=W:3D,JD,5D,7D\%3BN:2S,4S,6S,KS\%3BW:AD,6D,TD,9D\%3BW:5S,3S,TS,7S\%3BE:6H,5H,8H,QH\%3BN:KH,2H,TH,3H\%3BN:QD,JH,KD,8D\%3BS:AH,4D,9S,9H\%3BS:AC,2C,4C,8C\%3BS:JC,7C,9C,7H\%3BS:3C,5C,TC,4H\%3BN:KC,JS,6C,QC\%3BN:QS,AS,8S,2D\%3B\&deal=876.AT5.K97.AJ63\%20K5.83.A8432.Q752\%20Q932.KQ.QJ6.KT94\%20AJT4.J97642.T5.8\&vul=All\&dealer=S\&contract=3N\&declarer=S\&wintrick=9\&score=600\&str=\%E5\%9B\%A2\%E4\%BD\%93\%E8\%B5\%9B\%20\%E7\%AC\%AC7\%E8\%BD\%AE\%20\%E7\%89\%8C\%E5\%8F\%B7\%207\slash 12\&dealid=349432067\&pbnid=65731689\&from=singlemessage\&isappinstalled=0}}

\end{document}
```

any suggestion to make it working (looks like `%3B` in url had issue)

ref: add extra config in mmd command can solve it as well, see  https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-6/issues/163

Comment: duplicate as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13224/how-to-use-a-link-as-footnote-that-has-special-characters-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way to solve this

as stated in [How to use a link as footnote that has special characters inside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13224/how-to-use-a-link-as-footnote-that-has-special-characters-inside)

```
Isn't it enough to simple escape the % with \ or am I missing something here? That is:
\footnote{http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804826\%28Surface.10\%29.aspx}
```

Also stated in https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-6/issues/163, it can be solved by extra configuration in the tool