# url not working in footnotes - seems to require escape characters, but

Tags: url

I use `\url` which does not require to escape characters in an URL to make 
them acceptable for latex (specifically LuaLaTex). However when the same 
reference is included in a footnote, characters (especially `_` and `%` 
seem to required escaping. Am I missing somehting?

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document} 

Phoenizisch \url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch}
    and more text
    with the same ref in a footnote%
 \footnote{some text with the same url
          \url{{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch}}
        and a closing text.}%
    . After the footnote 

\end{document}
```

which does not compile with the error

```
File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.
```

It does, of course, compile and produce output as expected if the offending 
url in the footnote is removed. Note that the same url in the body is 
processed correctly. I assume that there is an interaction between `\footnote` and `\url`.

What is the best solution or workaround?

Comment: Have you tried `\protect\url` otherwise see the manual for the url package, the url command is fragile (afair)

Comment: `\url` changes the category-code-régime (beneath other things it changes the category codes of `_` and `%`) and "hopes" for its argument to be read from the .tex-input-file and tokenized under that changed category-code-régime. But the `\url`-command is cheated out of this hope in case of `\url{...}` being part of the argument of a `\footnote`-command because in this case things already got tokenized under normal/unchanged category-code-régime when the argument of the `\footnote`-command got read from the .tex-input-file and tokenized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use command `\urldef{\urlB}` to define the url you need and use `\urlB` to insert the wanted url into the footnote. That is also usable in normal text ...

Please see this mwe

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\urlA}\url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch} % <========
\urldef{\urlB}\url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch} % <========


\begin{document} 

Phoenizisch \urlA\  % <=================================================
    and more text
    with the same ref in a footnote%
 \footnote{some text with the same url
          \urlB\  % <===================================================
        and a closing text.}%
    . After the footnote 

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: footnote]

and the normal text:

[image: text]

Comment: Thank you -  I will use this solution, it solves the probem, but I still feel this is not a proper solution for a common problem when writing (putting URLs in footnote seems to strike a decent balance between pointing to your sources and not disturbing the flow of text). Latex should have a "proper" solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `\` before characters like `_`,`%`, or `#` when you use `\href` and/or `\url` in a footnote.
So, you can use the following code,

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document} 

Phoenizisch \url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Ph%C3%B6nizisch}
    and more text
    with the same ref in a footnote%  \footnote{some text with the same url
          \url{{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock\_Ph\%C3\%B6nizisch}}
        and a closing text.}%
    . After the footnote 

\end{document}
```