# LaTeX Combined hyper reference and footnote lacks verbatim argument behaviour

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, footnotes, verbatim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote)

Here's my first version of a clever command for URL-footnotes. It combines `pdftex`'s hyperlink behaviour with a `\footnote` displaying the URL.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\hrefn}[2]{\href{#1}{#2}\footnote{See {\tt #1}}} %HyperRef and Footnote in one
```

However it doesn't treat the input as verbatim as `\href` does. How do I **prevent** my command `\hrefn` from treating characters such as `#` and `~` as special control characters? I already `\usepackage{underscore}` so `_` are not a problem.

/Nordlöw

Comment: Put a \ in front of the character you want to be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` package has a command `\urldef` which allows you to define robust verbatim URLs that can be used in footnotes.

Also, since you’re using LaTeX, you shouldn’t be using `\tt` – use `\ttfamily` or `\texttt` instead.