# How can I include underscores in a footnote?

Tags: footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/getting-those-signs-in-the-footnote)

I'm trying to do

```
\footnote{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds}
```

And it appears to be breaking because of the underscores

```
\footnote{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TheWisdomofCrowds}
```

Seems fine.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the preamble:

```
 \usepackage{url}
```

and then:

```
\footnote{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `url` package as suggested in another answer is the preferred method. However, for the sake of completeness, another way to do this is to replace each instance of `_` with `\_`. The fixed footnote is `\footnote{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The\_Wisdom\_of\_Crowds}`.

Comment: However, if you mouse-over (or click) to the link in the final pdf, you will only see (or directed to) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The.