# Missing $ inserted issue

Tags: bibtex, errors, urls, doi

Trying to get my dissertation sorted (due in a few hours) and I keep getting this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.190 ... pp. 225--236, 10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_
                                                  18. [Online].
?
```

Really struggling to sort it out.

I'm fairly new to LaTeX.

Edit: This is 189-204 of the bibtex

```
@inproceedings{davis,
 author = {Davis, Alan and Dieste, Oscar and Hickey, Ann and Juristo, Natalia and Moreno, Ana M.},
 title = {Effectiveness of Requirements Elicitation Techniques: Empirical Results Derived from a Systematic Review},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 14th IEEE International Requirements Engineering Conference},
 series = {RE '06},
 year = {2006},
 isbn = {0-7695-2555-5},
 pages = {176--185},
 numpages = {10},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/RE.2006.17},
 doi = {10.1109/RE.2006.17},
 acmid = {1174006},
 publisher = {IEEE Computer Society},
 address = {Washington, DC, USA},
 keywords = {Systematic review, software engineering, elicitation techniques, empirical studies},
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You need to supply more information. What does your code look like around line 190 of the file? Seems like an entry in a bibliography. Edit your question and include that detail (perhaps the entire bibliography?).

Comment: The solution that avoids the error and liberates from having to change the urls is to
```
\usepackage{url}
```
as suggested [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51940/8666).

Comment: I resolved the same error with \_ instead of _ at the end of doi

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The line number in the error message is the line of the `.bbl` file that is generated by `bibtex`, it is not the line of the `.bib` file. Therefore the question quotes the wrong lines. The line in the error message contains:

```
pp. 225--236, 10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18. [Online].
```

Therefore I think the entry in the `.bib` file contains

```
doi = {10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18},
```

It seems the DOI numbers are not well supported. The prefix `doi:` is missing:

```
doi:10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18
```

Or as URL:

```
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18
```

Also special characters like `_` are not well supported. The `_` causes the trouble.
Make a minimal example (MWE) that shows, how the `doi` entries in the `.bib` file are handled in your document.

If there are no special macros that handle the `doi` numbers, then you can try `\_` instead of `_` in the `.bib` file.

Comment: Why should the prefix `doi:` be required for the DOI field? A doi number always starts with `10`, not with `doi:`

Comment: Another likely possibility that I ran into was simply attempting to use the .bib file as a .bbl. This will explain why the doi was not supported properly (underscore would have been supported in the .bib, but not in .bbl). See my answer.

Comment: @6005 The error message shows clearly that it comes from the `.bbl` file, not by including the `.bib` file in LaTeX.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek If you rename the .bib to a .bbl, you get this error. It just happened to me. When submitting to arXiv

Comment: @6005 Very likely this can be detected by seeing the key in the error message, e.g. `l42.   doi = 10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_`.

Comment: An underscore in a DOI brought me to this answer: changing it to `\_` solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

`\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; this completely **solves** the problem, whereas the currently-accepted answer merely *explains* the problem.

Comment: It did not work for me :(

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm using Overleaf and my bib file is synced from Mendeley. I keep getting a compile error whenever this is added in the preamble.

Comment: The `doi` package doesn't seem to work with the Springer style `splncs04.bst` which defines its own `doi` command in the bibliography preamble (`\providecommand{\doi}[1]{https://doi.org/#1}`). Hence, I favorise the solution with the `underscore` package.

Comment: This conflicts with some packages like pstricks, but works well if included in the end of preamble.

Comment: It actually could solve the issue, but can cause a lot of other conflicts when used without checking as also reported by @irene - more explanation could help here. Including in the end of the preamble like Fractalic suggests helped for me.

Comment: you are a life saver

Comment: @durbachit May be the problem is caused by `backref`. I had the same problem, it got resolved once I removed `backref`

Comment: @Mario Yep, just learnt it

Comment: @irene: In Overleaf, using `\usepackage{hyperref}` solves it.

Comment: Thanks god! This just works!

Answer (score 24):

The problem is the underscore  `_` in a `doi`. It occurs in line 190 of the LaTeX file (or in the `.bbl`) not in the `.bib` file.

Search for `10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18` in your `.bib` file. You can use the `url` package and enclose the entry in `\url{10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18}` to avoid the error. Alternatively you can use a `bibtex` style that knows about `doi`s.

Comment: It might also be necessary to delete and remake the .bbl file.  (I'm adding that for other readers.  Learned it the hard way.)

Answer (score 17):

Try using in the preamble `\usepackage{url}`.
This should clear the problem.

Comment: worked for me! I wonder why it got downvoted? It doesn't have any analysis or explanation of the problem, but it seems like the quickest fix. I am wary of changing my .bib file in case bibtex starts handling underscores correctly (i.e. without needing an escape character) and prints `\_` into the bibliography

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: This only works, if the error occurs in the URL field, not if it is in any other field (which still makes it a valuable answer!).

Comment: I'm using IEEE template. I did not have to enclose them in url as my error occurred in `@misc{online_ref1, author={}, title={}, url={...incorrect_url}, urldate={}}`. Adding `\usepackage{url}` solved my issue. It seems IEEE does not use the package by default.

Answer (score 3):

What Werner and Gonzalo said would indeed be very helpful. From the limited info given however, I guess LaTeX struggles with the `_` in the line, since it normally sees that as a subscript indicator and only expects it in math mode.

A very short solution (and impossible to say if that works without taking a look at the offending code) is to escape the underscore ("`_`"), by placing a backslash before it.

Comment: Which underscore?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to drop the whole "_18" as it says just "chapter 18". If you write "10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8" rather than "10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18" the reader will still be referred to the right book, but not to chapter 18 within it.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the underscore ("_"), you can use [shortdoi.org](http://shortdoi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18) and `doi:10/djzjd6` instead of `doi:10.1007/978-0-387-68772-8_18`, which is also nice when your readers need to type the doi from a printed version of your thesis instead of being able to click at it in an electronic document.

Answer (score 1):

Another future-proof answer, albeit rather tedious, is suggested [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2002-March/002379.html):

Change all occurrences of `_` in the URL field of your .bib file to their [html character code](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html) equivalent `%5F`

Comment: Why is this better than replacing `_` with `\_`?

Answer (score 1):

From [a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383678/underscore-in-bibtex-url), the answer that worked for me was adding

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble. (Or `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` to avoid the ugly boxes.)

Credit to Ulrike Fischer and CGFoX

Answer (score 1):

The short way:

1. open "*.bib" file
2. Replace:

   ```
        "-" >>>> "\_"
        "&" >>>> "\&" (specially check in the links)
        "\" >>>> "\\" (specially check in the links)
   ```
3. Delete all temporary files:
            In Texmaker:

   ```
        Tools -> Clean
        Bibliography -> Clean
   ```
4. You are done!
   Very Important Note: You **do not need** any extra package, so **do not use** them, in order to prevent further problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issue when submitting to arXiv, one possible source of the problem may be that **you are trying to use a .bib file as a .bbl**.

While renaming the .bib to .bbl is pretty silly in retrospect, that's what I did (not understanding that they are different). And then I ran into these errors. You need to submit the .bbl that is generated when you compile on your machine (or, in my case, download the .bbl file produced by ShareLaTeX online). The format of the .bbl is different from the .bib and the references will not show up correctly or be cited correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with the encoding. I used `\usepackage[macintosh]{inputenc}`.

I solved the problem by switching to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but i also had to update the encoding of my files by using `iconv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling complex tex when using new packages might incur even more problems, I find a simple solution by replacing the underscore in the bib files' DOI link with `\textunderscore`, like this:

```
doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-45738-3\textunderscore9}
```

It should solve your issue in a second.

Comment: Does the hyperlink work with this approach? If not, the other solutions would be better.