# Problem while using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like to use natbib in my document but I am getting some errors as you see in below figure:

[image]

here is my bibtext file:

```
@book{a1,
    author    = {Dennis Shasha and Yunyue Zhu},
    title     = {High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2004},
    note={ISBN: 0387008578}
 }
,
@book {a2,
 author    = {Christopher Chatfield},
    title     = {The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction},
    publisher = {Chapman\&Hall},
    year      = {2003},
    edition={sixth}, 
    note={ISBN: 1584883170}  
}
,
@book{a3,
    author    = {Dennis Shasha and Yunyue Zhu},
    title     = {High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies},

    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2004},
    note={ISBN: 0387008578}
 }
,
@incollection{a4,
year={2010},
note={ISBN: 978-0-387-30768-8},
booktitle={Encyclopedia of Machine Learning},
editor={Sammut, Claude and Webb, GeoffreyI.},
doi={10.1007/978-0-387-30164-8_177},
title={Correlation-Based Learning},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-30164-8_177},
publisher={Springer US},
pages={235},
language={English}
}
,
@article{a6,
AUTHOR    = {Dave Meko}, 
TITLE     = {Autocorelation},
JOURNAL   = {GEOS 585A, Applied Time Series Analysis},
YEAR      = {2013}
}
,
@book{a7,
   author={Bertrand Clarke and Ernest Fokoue and Hao Helen Zhang},
title = {Principles and Theory for Data Mining and Machine Learning},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year = {2008},
    note={ISBN: 9780387981352}

}
,
@book{a8,
title = {Introductory Time Series with R},
author = {Andrew V. Metcalfe and Paul S. P. Cowpertwait },
address = {New York, NY},
publisher = {Springer New York},
year = {2009},
note={ISBN: 9780387886985}
}
,
 @misc{a9,
  title  = {Confidence bands},
  author = {The National Foundation for Educational Research in England and Wales},
  note   = {\url{https://www.nfer.ac.uk/nfer/research/assessment/about/confidence-bands.cfm}}},
  year   = {2010 (accessed November 15, 2013)}
}
,

@misc{a10,
  title  = {Optische Zeitbereichsreflektometrie (OTDR)},
  note   = {\url{http://pi-mon.com/de/technologie/optische-zeitbereichsreflektometrie/}},
  year   = {(accessed November 15, 2013)},
}
    ,
@BOOK{a11,
   TITLE={Time Series Analysis Forcasting and Control},

   AUTHOR={Georg E. P. Box and Gwilym M. Jenkins and Gregory C. Reinsel},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Wiley},
   note={ISBN: 9780470272848}
}
,
@BOOK{a12,
   TITLE={Time Series Analysis Univariate and Multivariate Methods},
   AUTHOR={William Wei},
   YEAR={1990},
   PUBLISHER={Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
   note={ISBN: 0201159112}
}
,

@BOOK{a14,
  TITLE={Statistical Graphics for Univariate and Bivariate Data},
   AUTHOR={William G. Jacoby},
   YEAR={1997},
   PUBLISHER={Sage Publication Inc.},
   note={ISBN: 0761908994}
}
,
@BOOK{a15,
   TITLE={Feature Extraktion Construction and Selection a Data Mining Prespective},
   AUTHOR={Huan Liu and Hiroshi Motoda},
   YEAR={1998},
   PUBLISHER={Kluwer Academic},
   note={ISBN: 0792381963}
}
,
@BOOK{a16,
   TITLE={Data Mining: Verfahren, Prozesse, Anwendungsarchitektur},
   AUTHOR={Helge Petersohn},
   YEAR={2005},
   PUBLISHER={Oldenbourg},
   note={ISBN: 9783486577150}
}
,
@BOOK{a18,
   TITLE={Machinelles Lernen},
   AUTHOR={Ethem Alpaydin},
   YEAR={2004},
   PUBLISHER={Oldenbourg},
   note={ISBN: 9783486581140}
}
@BOOK{s1,
   TITLE={Spectral Analysis and Time Series},
   CHAPTER={Basic concepts},
   AUTHOR={Maurice B. Priestley},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Academic press},
   note={ISBN: 0125649223}
}
,
@misc{s5,
  title  = {Lesson 6: The Periodogram},
  note   = {\url {https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/?q=book/export/html/52}},
  year   = {(accessed Januar 12, 2014)}
}
,
@misc{s6,
  title  = {Understanding the Periodogram and Spectral Density},
  note   = {\url {http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.cs/spectral_cat_output.htm?lang=en}},
  year   = {(accessed Januar 14, 2014)}
}
,
@article{s7,
AUTHOR    = {Ta-Hsin Li}, 
TITLE     = {A robust periodogram for high-resolution spectral analysis},
JOURNAL   = {Signal Processing},
PAGES={2133-2140},
Volume={90},
YEAR      = {2010},
note={ISSN: "0165-1684"}
}
,

@misc{s8,
  title  = {Lexikon der Physik},
  note   = {\url {http://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/spektraldichte/13537}},
  year   = {(accessed August 20, 2014)}
}
,
@BOOK{s9,
   TITLE={Statistical Visions in Time: A History of Time Series Analysis, 1662-1938},
   CHAPTER={Decompostition and Functions of Time},
   AUTHOR={Judy L. Klein},
   YEAR={1997},
   PUBLISHER={Cambridge University Press},
   note={ISBN: 0521420466}
}
,
@INBOOK{k1,
   TITLE={Data Mining Techniques and Tools for Knowledge Discovery in Agricultural Datasets},
   AUTHOR={Ms. Anshu Bhardwaj},
   PAGES={139-144},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Indian Agricultural Statistics Research Institute},
   ADDRESS={Library Avenue, New Delhi}
}
,
@book {k2,
author={Igor Kononenko and Matjazkukar.},
title     = {Machine Learning and Data Mining, introduction to principles and algorithms},
 publisher = {Horwood Publishing Chichester, UK},
    year      = {2007},
  note={ISBN: 1904275214}
}  
,

@book {k3,
    author    = {J. P. Marques de Sá},
    title     = {Pattern recognition ; concepts, methods and applications},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2001},
    note={ISBN: 3540422978}   
}
,

@BOOK {k4,
    author    = {Thuraisingham, Bhavani M.},
    title     = {Data mining ; technologies, techniques, tools, and trends},
    publisher = {CRC Press LLC},
    year      = {1999},
    note={ISBN: 0849318157}  
}
,
@misc{k6,
  title  = {"Welcome to the SAX (Symbolic Aggregate approXimation) Homepage!"},
  author = {E. Keogh},
  note   = {\url{http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.htm}},
  year   = {2007 (accessed Januar 27, 2017)},
}
,

@incollection {k7,    
   author = {Pavel V. Senin},    
   affiliation = {Collaborative Software Development Lab
Department of Information and Computer Sciences
University of Hawaii
Honolulu, HI},    
   title = {Literature Review on Time Series Indexing},        
   pages = {23-25},    
   url = {http://www2.hawaii.edu/~senin/assets/papers/senin-trajectory-litreview.pdf},        
   year = {2009}    
}
,
@misc{k8,
  title  = {"Do Splitting Rules Really Matter?"},
   author = {Salford systems},
  note   = {\url{https://www.salford-systems.com/resources/whitepapers/114-do-splitting-rules-really-matter}},
  year   = { (accessed Januar 27, 2017)},
}
,
@misc{k9,
  title  = {"Categorical variables : Solving the overfitting problem in decision trees."},
   author = {zyxo},
  note   = {\url{http://zyxo.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/categorical-variables-solving-the-overfitting-problem-in-decision-trees/}},
  year   = { 2010 (accessed Februar 07, 2014)}
}
,

@article{k10,
AUTHOR    = {Roger J. Lewis}, 
TITLE     = {An Introduction to Classification and Regression Tree (CART) Analysis},
JOURNAL   = { Annual Meeting of the Society for Academic Emergency Medicine},
YEAR      = {2000}
}
,
@BOOK {k11,
 author={Mehmed Kantardzic},
 title     = {Data Mining},
 publisher = {Wiley-IEEE Press},
 year      = {2011},
 note={ISBN: 9781283239745}
} 
,

@BOOK {k12,
    author= {Theophano Mitsa},
    title     = {Temporal Data Mining},
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    year    = {2010},
    note={ISBN: 1420089765}
} 
,

@conference{k17,
    author    = {Nguyen Quoc Viet Hung and Duong Tuan Anh},
    title     = {Combining SAX and Piecewise Linear Approximation to Improve Similarity Search on Financial Time Series},
    booktitle = {International Symposium on Information Technology Convergence},
    year      = {2007}
}
,

@article{k18,
    author    = {Jessica Lin Eamonn Keogh Stefano Lonardi Bill Chiu},
    title     = {A Symbolic Representation of Time Series, with Implications for
Streaming Algorithms}
}
,
@Book{k19,
author = {Geoff Dougherty},
title = {Pattern Recognition and Classification},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2013},
note={ISBN: 9781461453239}
}
,
@article{k20,
AUTHOR    = {Pavel Senin and Sergey Malinchik}, 
TITLE     = {SAX-VSM: Interpretable Time Series Classification Using SAX and Vector Space Model}
}
,
@article{k21,
AUTHOR    = {Jessica Lin and Rohan Khade and Yuan Li}, 
TITLE     = {Rotation-invariant similarity in time series using bag-of-patterns representation},
JOURNAL   = {Journal of Intelligent Information Systems},
YEAR      = {2012},
VOLUME= {39},
ISSUE = {2},
PAGES= {287-315}
}
,
@incollection{k25,
       author={Hiroaki Sakoe and Seibi Chiba},
       year={1978},
       title={Dynamic Programming Algorithm Optimization for 
Spoken Word Recognition},
       booktitle={IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON ACOUSTICS, SPEECH, AND SIGNAL PROCESSING},
       note={ISSN: 0096-3518}
     }
,
@misc{k26,
  title  = {DTW algorithm},
  note   = {\url{http://www.psb.ugent.be/cbd/papers/gentxwarper/DTWalgorithm.htm}},
  year   = { 2010 (accessed Februar 27, 2014)}
}
,
@article{k27,
AUTHOR    = {Kaushik Chakrabarti and Eemonn Keogh}, 
TITLE     = {Locally Adaptive Dimensionality Reduction for Indexing Large Time Series Databases}
}
,
@BOOK{k28,
   TITLE={Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery Handbook},
   AUTHOR={Chotirat Ann Ralanamahatana and Jessica Lin and Dimitrios Gunopulos and Eamonn Keogh, Michail Vlachos and Gautam Das},
   YEAR={2005},
   PUBLISHER={Springer US},
   note={ISBN: 9780387244358}
}
,
@book {k29,
 author    = {Huan Liu Hiroshi motoda},
    title     = {Feature Extraction construction and selection a data Mining prespective},
    publisher = {Kluwer Academic Publishers},
    year      = {1998},
    note={ISBN: 0792381963}  
}
,
@incollection{k30,
       author={Ramakrishna Murty and J.V.R Murthy and Prasad Reddy P.V.G.D},
       year={2011},
       title={Text Document Classification based-on Least
Square Support Vector Machines with Singular
Value Decomposition},
       booktitle={International Journal of Computer Applications (0975 – 8887)},
       VOLUME={27}
     }
,

@incollection{k31,
       author={ Sotiris B. Kotsiantis},
       year={Nummer3 2007},
       title={Supervised Machine Learning: A Review of Classification
Techniques},
       booktitle={Informatica (Slovenia)},
       PAGES={249-268},
       VOLUME={31}
     }
,
@book {k32,
 author    = {Mehmed Kantardizic},
    title     = {Data Mining Concepts, Models, Methods, and Algorithms},
    publisher = {Wily},
    year      = {2011},
    note={ISBN: 9781118029145}  
}
,
@book {k33,
 author    = {Michael W. Berry and Murray Browne},
    title     = {Lecture Notes in Data Mining},
    publisher = {World Scientific Publishing Co. Pte. Ltd.},
    year      = {2006},
    note={ISBN: 9812568026}  
}
,
@BOOK {kz2,
    author= {Theophano Mitsa},
    title     = {Temporal Data Mining},
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    year    = {2010},
    note={ISBN: 1420089765}
} 
,
@Book{kz5,
author = {Richard O. Duda and Peter E. Hart and David G. Strok},
title = {Pattern Classification},
publisher = {A Wiley-Interscience Publication},
year = {2001},
note={ISBN: 0471056693}
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you removed `cite` from the list of packages that are loaded in the preamble? If you use `natbib`, you shouldn't load `cite` as well.

Comment: I have tried it again withot ´cite´, but errors still remain

Comment: You have a plenty of errors in the bib file. Hard to tell where to begin. Which bibliography style do you employ? (If you're using `plainnat`, at least the DOI-related error would go away on its own.)

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71215/missing-inserted-issue

Comment: I'm glad you've found a fix for the underscore character in one of the DOI fields. Do please also fix the slew of other, content-related errors. Among them are missing `and` particles between authors, e.g., `Huan Liu Hiroshi motoda` and `Jessica Lin Eamonn Keogh Stefano Lonardi Bill Chiu`; extraneous information, e.g., "Ms." in `Ms. Anshu Bhardwaj`; missing pairs of curly braces around "corporate" authors, e.g., `Salford Systems`; non-ASCII characters, e.g., `á` in `J. P. Marques de Sá`; repeat entries (e.g., keys `k12` and `kz2`). And, please get rid of the pointless commas *between* entries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve your problem, you can simply load the package `doi`

```
\usepackage{doi}
```

so you'll be able to use underscores `_` in your `doi` and `url` fields. Also, your fields will have links.

At these point, since your `doi`s have already a link, you can eliminate `url`s from those entries.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a1,
    author    = {Dennis Shasha and Yunyue Zhu},
    title     = {High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2004},
    note={ISBN: 0387008578}
 }
,
@book {a2,
 author    = {Christopher Chatfield},
    title     = {The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction},
    publisher = {Chapman\&Hall},
    year      = {2003},
    edition={sixth},
    note={ISBN: 1584883170}
}
,
@book{a3,
    author    = {Dennis Shasha and Yunyue Zhu},
    title     = {High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies},

    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2004},
    note={ISBN: 0387008578}
 }
,
@incollection{a4,
year={2010},
note={ISBN: 978-0-387-30768-8},
booktitle={Encyclopedia of Machine Learning},
editor={Sammut, Claude and Webb, GeoffreyI.},
doi={10.1007/978-0-387-30164-8_177},
title={Correlation-Based Learning},
publisher={Springer US},
pages={235},
language={English}
}
,
@article{a6,
AUTHOR    = {Dave Meko},
TITLE     = {Autocorelation},
JOURNAL   = {GEOS 585A, Applied Time Series Analysis},
YEAR      = {2013}
}
,
@book{a7,
   author={Bertrand Clarke and Ernest Fokoue and Hao Helen Zhang},
title = {Principles and Theory for Data Mining and Machine Learning},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year = {2008},
    note={ISBN: 9780387981352}

}
,
@book{a8,
title = {Introductory Time Series with R},
author = {Andrew V. Metcalfe and Paul S. P. Cowpertwait },
address = {New York, NY},
publisher = {Springer New York},
year = {2009},
note={ISBN: 9780387886985}
}
,
 @misc{a9,
  title  = {Confidence bands},
  author = {The National Foundation for Educational Research in England and Wales},
  note   = {\url{https://www.nfer.ac.uk/nfer/research/assessment/about/confidence-bands.cfm}}},
  year   = {2010 (accessed November 15, 2013)}
}
,

@misc{a10,
  title  = {Optische Zeitbereichsreflektometrie (OTDR)},
  note   = {\url{http://pi-mon.com/de/technologie/optische-zeitbereichsreflektometrie/}},
  year   = {(accessed November 15, 2013)},
}
    ,
@BOOK{a11,
   TITLE={Time Series Analysis Forcasting and Control},

   AUTHOR={Georg E. P. Box and Gwilym M. Jenkins and Gregory C. Reinsel},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Wiley},
   note={ISBN: 9780470272848}
}
,
@BOOK{a12,
   TITLE={Time Series Analysis Univariate and Multivariate Methods},
   AUTHOR={William Wei},
   YEAR={1990},
   PUBLISHER={Addison-Wesley Publishing Company},
   note={ISBN: 0201159112}
}
,

@BOOK{a14,
  TITLE={Statistical Graphics for Univariate and Bivariate Data},
   AUTHOR={William G. Jacoby},
   YEAR={1997},
   PUBLISHER={Sage Publication Inc.},
   note={ISBN: 0761908994}
}
,
@BOOK{a15,
   TITLE={Feature Extraktion Construction and Selection a Data Mining Prespective},
   AUTHOR={Huan Liu and Hiroshi Motoda},
   YEAR={1998},
   PUBLISHER={Kluwer Academic},
   note={ISBN: 0792381963}
}
,
@BOOK{a16,
   TITLE={Data Mining: Verfahren, Prozesse, Anwendungsarchitektur},
   AUTHOR={Helge Petersohn},
   YEAR={2005},
   PUBLISHER={Oldenbourg},
   note={ISBN: 9783486577150}
}
,
@BOOK{a18,
   TITLE={Machinelles Lernen},
   AUTHOR={Ethem Alpaydin},
   YEAR={2004},
   PUBLISHER={Oldenbourg},
   note={ISBN: 9783486581140}
}
@BOOK{s1,
   TITLE={Spectral Analysis and Time Series},
   CHAPTER={Basic concepts},
   AUTHOR={Maurice B. Priestley},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Academic press},
   note={ISBN: 0125649223}
}
,
@misc{s5,
  title  = {Lesson 6: The Periodogram},
  note   = {\url {https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/?q=book/export/html/52}},
  year   = {(accessed Januar 12, 2014)}
}
,
@misc{s6,
  title  = {Understanding the Periodogram and Spectral Density},
  note   = {\url {http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.cs/spectral_cat_output.htm?lang=en}},
  year   = {(accessed Januar 14, 2014)}
}
,
@article{s7,
AUTHOR    = {Ta-Hsin Li},
TITLE     = {A robust periodogram for high-resolution spectral analysis},
JOURNAL   = {Signal Processing},
PAGES={2133-2140},
Volume={90},
YEAR      = {2010},
note={ISSN: "0165-1684"}
}
,

@misc{s8,
  title  = {Lexikon der Physik},
  note   = {\url {http://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/spektraldichte/13537}},
  year   = {(accessed August 20, 2014)}
}
,
@BOOK{s9,
   TITLE={Statistical Visions in Time: A History of Time Series Analysis, 1662-1938},
   CHAPTER={Decompostition and Functions of Time},
   AUTHOR={Judy L. Klein},
   YEAR={1997},
   PUBLISHER={Cambridge University Press},
   note={ISBN: 0521420466}
}
,
@INBOOK{k1,
   TITLE={Data Mining Techniques and Tools for Knowledge Discovery in Agricultural Datasets},
   AUTHOR={Ms. Anshu Bhardwaj},
   PAGES={139-144},
   YEAR={2001},
   PUBLISHER={Indian Agricultural Statistics Research Institute},
   ADDRESS={Library Avenue, New Delhi}
}
,
@book {k2,
author={Igor Kononenko and Matjazkukar.},
title     = {Machine Learning and Data Mining, introduction to principles and algorithms},
 publisher = {Horwood Publishing Chichester, UK},
    year      = {2007},
  note={ISBN: 1904275214}
}
,

@book {k3,
    author    = {J. P. Marques de Sá},
    title     = {Pattern recognition ; concepts, methods and applications},
    publisher = {Springer},
    year      = {2001},
    note={ISBN: 3540422978}
}
,

@BOOK {k4,
    author    = {Thuraisingham, Bhavani M.},
    title     = {Data mining ; technologies, techniques, tools, and trends},
    publisher = {CRC Press LLC},
    year      = {1999},
    note={ISBN: 0849318157}
}
,
@misc{k6,
  title  = {"Welcome to the SAX (Symbolic Aggregate approXimation) Homepage!"},
  author = {E. Keogh},
  note   = {\url{http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.htm}},
  year   = {2007 (accessed Januar 27, 2017)},
}
,

@incollection {k7,
   author = {Pavel V. Senin},
   affiliation = {Collaborative Software Development Lab
Department of Information and Computer Sciences
University of Hawaii
Honolulu, HI},
   title = {Literature Review on Time Series Indexing},
   pages = {23-25},
   url = {http://www2.hawaii.edu/~senin/assets/papers/senin-trajectory-litreview.pdf},
   year = {2009}
}
,
@misc{k8,
  title  = {"Do Splitting Rules Really Matter?"},
   author = {Salford systems},
  note   = {\url{https://www.salford-systems.com/resources/whitepapers/114-do-splitting-rules-really-matter}},
  year   = { (accessed Januar 27, 2017)},
}
,
@misc{k9,
  title  = {"Categorical variables : Solving the overfitting problem in decision trees."},
   author = {zyxo},
  note   = {\url{http://zyxo.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/categorical-variables-solving-the-overfitting-problem-in-decision-trees/}},
  year   = { 2010 (accessed Februar 07, 2014)}
}
,

@article{k10,
AUTHOR    = {Roger J. Lewis},
TITLE     = {An Introduction to Classification and Regression Tree (CART) Analysis},
JOURNAL   = { Annual Meeting of the Society for Academic Emergency Medicine},
YEAR      = {2000}
}
,
@BOOK {k11,
 author={Mehmed Kantardzic},
 title     = {Data Mining},
 publisher = {Wiley-IEEE Press},
 year      = {2011},
 note={ISBN: 9781283239745}
}
,

@BOOK {k12,
    author= {Theophano Mitsa},
    title     = {Temporal Data Mining},
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    year    = {2010},
    note={ISBN: 1420089765}
}
,

@conference{k17,
    author    = {Nguyen Quoc Viet Hung and Duong Tuan Anh},
    title     = {Combining SAX and Piecewise Linear Approximation to Improve Similarity Search on Financial Time Series},
    booktitle = {International Symposium on Information Technology Convergence},
    year      = {2007}
}
,

@article{k18,
    author    = {Jessica Lin Eamonn Keogh Stefano Lonardi Bill Chiu},
    title     = {A Symbolic Representation of Time Series, with Implications for
Streaming Algorithms}
}
,
@Book{k19,
author = {Geoff Dougherty},
title = {Pattern Recognition and Classification},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {2013},
note={ISBN: 9781461453239}
}
,
@article{k20,
AUTHOR    = {Pavel Senin and Sergey Malinchik},
TITLE     = {SAX-VSM: Interpretable Time Series Classification Using SAX and Vector Space Model}
}
,
@article{k21,
AUTHOR    = {Jessica Lin and Rohan Khade and Yuan Li},
TITLE     = {Rotation-invariant similarity in time series using bag-of-patterns representation},
JOURNAL   = {Journal of Intelligent Information Systems},
YEAR      = {2012},
VOLUME= {39},
ISSUE = {2},
PAGES= {287-315}
}
,
@incollection{k25,
       author={Hiroaki Sakoe and Seibi Chiba},
       year={1978},
       title={Dynamic Programming Algorithm Optimization for
Spoken Word Recognition},
       booktitle={IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON ACOUSTICS, SPEECH, AND SIGNAL PROCESSING},
       note={ISSN: 0096-3518}
     }
,
@misc{k26,
  title  = {DTW algorithm},
  note   = {\url{http://www.psb.ugent.be/cbd/papers/gentxwarper/DTWalgorithm.htm}},
  year   = { 2010 (accessed Februar 27, 2014)}
}
,
@article{k27,
AUTHOR    = {Kaushik Chakrabarti and Eemonn Keogh},
TITLE     = {Locally Adaptive Dimensionality Reduction for Indexing Large Time Series Databases}
}
,
@BOOK{k28,
   TITLE={Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery Handbook},
   AUTHOR={Chotirat Ann Ralanamahatana and Jessica Lin and Dimitrios Gunopulos and Eamonn Keogh, Michail Vlachos and Gautam Das},
   YEAR={2005},
   PUBLISHER={Springer US},
   note={ISBN: 9780387244358}
}
,
@book {k29,
 author    = {Huan Liu Hiroshi motoda},
    title     = {Feature Extraction construction and selection a data Mining prespective},
    publisher = {Kluwer Academic Publishers},
    year      = {1998},
    note={ISBN: 0792381963}
}
,
@incollection{k30,
       author={Ramakrishna Murty and J.V.R Murthy and Prasad Reddy P.V.G.D},
       year={2011},
       title={Text Document Classification based-on Least
Square Support Vector Machines with Singular
Value Decomposition},
       booktitle={International Journal of Computer Applications (0975 – 8887)},
       VOLUME={27}
     }
,

@incollection{k31,
       author={ Sotiris B. Kotsiantis},
       year={Nummer3 2007},
       title={Supervised Machine Learning: A Review of Classification
Techniques},
       booktitle={Informatica (Slovenia)},
       PAGES={249-268},
       VOLUME={31}
     }
,
@book {k32,
 author    = {Mehmed Kantardizic},
    title     = {Data Mining Concepts, Models, Methods, and Algorithms},
    publisher = {Wily},
    year      = {2011},
    note={ISBN: 9781118029145}
}
,
@book {k33,
 author    = {Michael W. Berry and Murray Browne},
    title     = {Lecture Notes in Data Mining},
    publisher = {World Scientific Publishing Co. Pte. Ltd.},
    year      = {2006},
    note={ISBN: 9812568026}
}
,
@BOOK {kz2,
    author= {Theophano Mitsa},
    title     = {Temporal Data Mining},
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    year    = {2010},
    note={ISBN: 1420089765}
}
,
@Book{kz5,
author = {Richard O. Duda and Peter E. Hart and David G. Strok},
title = {Pattern Classification},
publisher = {A Wiley-Interscience Publication},
year = {2001},
note={ISBN: 0471056693}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{doi} 

\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 :-)  By the way, if the `plainnat` (or `unsrtnat`) bibliography style is used (as is the case in your example), the contents of `doi` fields are automatically treated in a special way. Loading the `doi` package won't do any harm, of course.

Comment: @Mico Loading `doi` you are allowed to use `_` in `doi`s (and `url`s).

Comment: My bad. I failed to mention that for `plainnat` and `unsrtnat` to handle `doi` fields that contain `_` characters properly, either the `url` or the `hyperref` package has be to be loaded as well (unless, of course, the `doi` package is loaded). Given the multitude of URLs in the OP's bib file, it's hopefully not a stretch to assume that one or the other package (or even both) are loaded by the OP.

Comment: `uri` is better than `doi`.