# Missing $ inserted issue bibliography LLNCS template

Tags: bibtex, errors, urls, doi

I'm getting a weird missing $  error in my bibliography

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
%
\title{adsnvuadsipnvewjl\thanks{Supported by University of Alberta}}
 \author{Hao Sun\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0002-2000-8080} 
 }
%
\authorrunning{Hao Sun}
\institute{University of Alberta, Alberta, Canada}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
 jasdkflasdgfhudafyhebvkcyfhdsuifgakhewnfcgyuzshvcdsyuafcgkdsh 
nbcvasdkfhvuban,vcyuaebvndskaguyrhvba.
\keywords{advdasv dav}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
Our problem is one of Karp's original 21 NP-hard problems \cite{Karp1972}. 

%
% ---- Bibliography ----
%
% BibTeX users should specify bibliography style 'splncs04'.
% References will then be sorted and formatted in the correct style.
%
 \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
 \bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

main.bib:

```
@Inbook{Karp1972,
author="Karp, Richard M.",
editor="Miller, Raymond E.
and Thatcher, James W.
and Bohlinger, Jean D.",
title="Reducibility among Combinatorial Problems",
bookTitle="Complexity of Computer Computations: Proceedings of a symposium on the Complexity of Computer Computations, held March 20--22, 1972, at the IBM Thomas J. Watson Research Center, Yorktown Heights, New York, and sponsored by the Office of Naval Research, Mathematics Program, IBM World Trade Corporation, and the IBM Research Mathematical Sciences Department",
year="1972",
publisher="Springer US",
address="Boston, MA",
pages="85--103",
abstract="",
isbn="978-1-4684-2001-2",
doi="10.1007/978-1-4684-2001-2_9",
url="https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-2001-2_9"
}
```

I've seen the solution   [Missing $ inserted issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71215/missing-inserted-issue)
to use  \usepackage[strings]{underscore}  but that conflicts with too many things in my actual paper so I'm hoping for something simpler.

Comment: When I compile your code on my system, I'm afraid I am unable to generate the error message you say you've encountered.

Comment: @Mico  See here  https://www.overleaf.com/read/ftgfzjsrzdwp#468519

Comment: Incidentally, one of the warning messages you're receiving is trying to tell you that you should be using the entry type `@incollection`, not `@inbook`, for the `Karp1972` entry.

Comment: Thanks for providing this link. It looks like Overleaf is using an obsolete, and faulty, version of the `llncs` document class: version 2.20, 10 Mar 2018. In contrast, on my system (MacTeX2023, all updates applied), I find `llncs 2022/09/05 v2.22` in the log file. Is there any chance you could switch to a TeX distribution that uses a more up to date version of the `llncs` document class?