# doi hyperlinks show up as "doi:doi" in my references

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, apacite, doi

I am using the `apacite` and `hyperref` packages and the `apacite` bibliography style to create the formatted bibliographic entries for my document in APA style on TexWorks using BibTex. I would like for the DOIs in my bibliography to link to their DOI URLs.

Using the package `doi` converts them to links, but every link in my bibliography now shows up as, e.g.

> Author. (year). Title.*Journal.* Vol (Issue).pages. **doi:
> doi**:10.2214/ajr.12.9928

The entry in my .bib file contains

```
doi = {10.2214/ajr.12.9928},
```

How do I remove the extra 'doi:'?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to deal with this.

1. Tell the `doi` package to drop its "doi:" prefix, which is saved in `\doitext`.

   ```
   \documentclass[british]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{babel}
   \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \usepackage{doi}
   \renewcommand{\doitext}{}

   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{appleby,
     author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
     title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
     year    = {1980},
     journal = {Civil Service Journal},
     doi     = {10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}
   \cite{appleby}
   \bibliographystyle{apacite}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Appleby, H. (1980). On the importance of the civil service. Civil Service Journal. doi:10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##]
2. Tell `apacite` to drop its "doi:" prefix, which is saved in `\doiprefix`.

   ```
   \documentclass[british]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{babel}
   \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \usepackage{doi}

   \renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}

   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{appleby,
     author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
     title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
     year    = {1980},
     journal = {Civil Service Journal},
     doi     = {10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}
   \cite{appleby}
   \bibliographystyle{apacite}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Appleby, H. (1980). On the importance of the civil service. Civil Service Journal. doi:10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##]
3. Build your own `\doi` command without prefix and don't load the `doi` package. Since you are loading `hyperref` I recommend to follow the slightly more complicated approach by [Michael Ummels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4087/michael-ummels) in [Getting those %#!^& signs in the footnote!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12855/35864). That will allow you to use 'dangerous' characters in the DOI without having to worry about most of them (as opposed to the more straightforward `\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}`, which would break if the DOI contained `#` or `%`.).

   ```
   \documentclass[british]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{babel}
   \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \newcommand*{\doi}{}
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\doi@}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}
   \DeclareRobustCommand{\doi}{\hyper@normalise\doi@}
   \makeatother

   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{appleby,
     author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
     title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
     year    = {1980},
     journal = {Civil Service Journal},
     doi     = {10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}
   \cite{appleby}
   \bibliographystyle{apacite}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Appleby, H. (1980). On the importance of the civil service. Civil Service Journal. doi:10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##]

Comment: **@moewe**: I would like to follow the third approach, and redefine the doi commmand, but with the latest APA 7 doi format instead, i.e.: `https://doi.org/10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##`. I'm not familiar with `\newcommand`, `\href`, etc. Could you clarify how these latter commands work? You have `\href{https://doi.org/...` in your code, but I still do not get the desired doi format in my output file

Comment: @Euclides Try `\newcommand{\doi@}[1]{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}` instead of `\newcommand{\doi@}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}` in the third code example.

Answer (score 1):

For APA 7th DOI style: `https://doi.org/10.2214/ajr.12.9928__##` (all as a link) as asked by **@euclides** you need to suppress the doi text. So combining **@moewe's** answers:

```
\newcommand*{\doi}{}
\renewcommand{\doiprefix}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doi@}[1]{\urlstyle{same}\url{https://doi.org/#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\doi}{\hyper@normalise\doi@}
\makeatother
```