# hyperref external reference

Tags: hyperref, xr

I want to reference external documents using hyperref on the files test1 and test2 below. Presumably for security reasons, the links don't work. With MacOs Preview nothing happens and Adobe Reader in both MacOs and Windows 10 keeps on asking for permissions.

I have no problems with older distributions of hyperref on older operating systems and applications.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Nestor

```
%----------------------------------------------
% file test1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{test2}
\begin{document}
\section{Section in I}\label{sec1}
Continued in \hyperref[sec2]{section~\ref*{sec2}}.
\end{document}
%----------------------------------------------
% file test2.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{test1}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Section in II}\label{sec2}
Continuing from \hyperref[sec1]{Section~\ref*{sec1}}.
\end{document}
%----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is nothing hyperref can change. If your system has security settings that suppress link to external document you have to change these security settings.

Comment: Moreover, MacOS Preview seems to have some difficulties dealing with external links as per [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540894/inconsistent-url-encoding-between-macoss-preview-and-adobe-acrobat).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this happens in both macos and windows newer systems. I cannot ask readers of documents posted in internet to change their security settings. Does this mean that xr-hyper is useless nowadays?

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to add links to external local files in documents posted on the internet. Embed the files. See packages embedfile, attachfile2 or intopdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why doesn't it make much sense? As I understand, embedfile and others will make the pdf larger and larger. If I am issuing notes on a course referencing to previous notes, will I have an enormous 10th pdf file?, will the 10th pdf have (1 + 2 + ... + 9) = 45 embedded files?

Comment: You will have to provide the external file anyway. Without it the link can not work, can't it? It is only a simple file link, not a fully qualified url. Btw: I just realized that the newest xr-hyper is still broken, it adds to many braces to the file link.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Humm, surely I will have to provide the external file, but if it is embedded in a second file this will enlarge the second file, right? If #1 file is embedded in #2 file and #2 file is embedded in #3 file, this means that the #3 file will have the first two (the first one actually duplicated) and I will still have to provide the other two separately, would that be so? I would certainly hope that you to look into the problem in the newest xr-hyper, as I wouldn't know what to do. Thanks for your patience.