# Insert footnotes with \href

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, urls

This seems like a very common practice, but an hour of researching the question has gotten me nowhere.  Is it not possible to insert the URI for the call to `\href` (`#1`) as a footnote?

I've tried defining a new command like so:

```
\newcommand{\fref}[2]{\href{#1}{#2}\footnote{\url{#1}}}
```

but the `footnotetext` is never produced.

---

A minimal example, if there must be one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hi!  \href{http://www.ctan.org}{CTAN} is a pretty cool place.
\end{document}
```

Desired output:

> Hi!  [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org)[1] is a pretty cool place.
>
> [1]: http://www.ctan.org

Comment: Try Using a normal footnote with '\protect' before the URL?

Comment: @LostBrit `\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{#2}\footnote{\protect\url{#1}}}` doesn't work.  Thanks for the idea, though.\

Comment: Your MWE would work perfectly if you replaced `\href` by `\fref` :)

Comment: I swear it hadn't before.  I must have inadvertently re-written hyperref.  That's the most obvious solution to this conundrum.  (My brain a splode this week.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a different way of asking the same question that is raised in [How display the href link in the footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/how-display-the-href-link-in-the-footnote?rq=1).

The solution that is posted there, does almost exactly what you need. For completeness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\fnurl[2]{%
\href{#2}{#1}\footnote{\url{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
hello \fnurl{CTAN}{http://www.ctan.org}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any actual linking going on (save between footnotemark and footnotetext)---I'm not really sure why; the call to `\href` should (by my understanding) have done the job.  This works wonderfully for documents to be distributed by print only, but doesn't incorporate the advantage of on-line viewing.

Comment: well, there is - but only the 1 in the footnote. Give me a minute...

Comment: Fixed. I have updated the answer and will now stop fiddling.

Comment: I could have sworn I went through all ... 40134 questions... one by one.  Thanks for finding the single one I miss!  I'll vote to close this as a duplicate so the original can get more love.  (Although, future generations should note that there is no problem in reversing the argument order as I initially (and silently) suspected. `\let\oldhref\href\renewcommand{\href}[2]{\oldhref{#1}{#2}\footnote{\url{#1}}}` is a drop-in replacement.)